# Calculate Michaelis-Menten constant of enzyme catalyzed reaction

Tags: analytical-chemistry, biochemistry, enzyme-kinetics

I have:

$$\begin{array}{c|c} 
\dfrac{v }{ [S]}/\pu{s^{-1}} & v \cdot 10^2/\pu{mol dm^-3 s^-1} \\ \hline
0.257\ & 5.15\\
0.895 & 4.48\\ 
2.00\ & 3.35\\ 
3.59\ & 1.8\\ 
4.82\ & 0.48\\ 
\hline
\end{array}$$

And I want to calculate $K_M$ graphically.

I know that I should use the equation:

$$\frac{1}{v}=\frac{1}{v_\mathrm{max}}+\frac{K_M}{v_\mathrm{max}[S]},$$

and that I should plot $1/v$ against $1/[S]$, and then the slope will equal $K_M$/$v_\mathrm{max}$.

I began with converting the data given from $v/[S]$ to $1/[S]$ by dividing each data point with $v$. This gave:

$$\begin{array}{c|c} 
\dfrac{1}{[S]}/\pu{dm^3 mol^{-1}} & v \cdot 10^2/\pu{mol dm^-3 s^-1} \\ \hline
4.99*10^{-4}\ & 5.15\\
0.0019 & 4.48\\ 
0.0059\ & 3.35\\ 
0.0199\ & 1.8\\ 
0.1004\ & 0.48\\ 
\hline
\end{array}$$

Plotting $1/v$ against $1/[S]$ gives the graph:

[image: Plot of 1/v vs 1/[S]]

But when I want to calculate $K_M$ through:
$$\text{slope} \times V_\mathrm{max} = \text{slope} \times \frac{1}{\text{intercept}}$$
I don't get the answer which is in our answer key. Unfortunately, only the answer for $K_M$ is given, and not how to get the answer. The answer is $K_M = \pu{0.0102 mol dm-3}$. Could someone explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: Your calculations are wrong on $\frac{1}{\ce{[S]}}$.

Comment: You somehow reversed the order of the data points, too. That's why there is a hyperbole and not a straight line. Because of the format of the data, it is easier to do an Eadie Hofstee fit instead of the Lineweaver-Burk you attempted.

Comment: When I am editing your question, I realized you have plot $\frac{1}{[S]}$ vs $v$ instead of $\frac{1}{[S]} $ vs $\frac{1}{v} $. That's why you got a hyperbole instead of straight-line as  Karsten Theis suggested.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne I think the values plotted represent 1/v (off by a factor 100), but are in the wrong order, i.e. the first substrate concentration is plotted against the last rate etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have given is:
$$\begin{array}{c|c} 
\hline
\dfrac{v}{[S]}, \ \pu{s^{-1}} & v, \ \pu{mol dm^-3 s^-1} \\ \hline
0.257  & 5.15 \times 10^{-2}\\
0.895 & 4.48 \times 10^{-2}\\ 
2.00  & 3.35 \times 10^{-2}\\ 
3.59  & 1.8 \times 10^{-2}\\ 
4.82  & 0.48 \times 10^{-2}\\ 
\hline
\end{array}$$

Michaelis-Menten equation for enzyme kinetics is:

$$v = \frac{V_\mathrm{max} \cdot [S]}{K_M + [S]} \tag1$$

When rearrange this equation (reciprocal) to get Lineweaver-Burk relationship:

$$\frac{1}{v} = \frac{1}{V_\mathrm{max}} + \frac{K_M}{V_\mathrm{max}[S]} \tag2$$

When multiply the equation $(2)$ by $v \times V_\mathrm{max}$, you get:

$$V_\mathrm{max} = v + \frac{vK_M}{[S]} \tag3$$

When rearrange the equation $(3)$, you get $y = mx + c$ type equation (straight-line equation):

$$v  = - K_M \cdot \frac{v}{[S]} + V_\mathrm{max} \tag4$$

The data you have is $\frac{v}{[S]}$ and $v$, which fix the relationship given in the equation $(4)$. Thus, if you can plot them against each other ($\frac{v}{[S]}$ versus $v$) you'd get a straight line with negative lope. The numerical value of the slope is $K_M$ so you can calculate K$_M$ graphically. Also, the $y$-intercept of the graph is equal to $V_\mathrm{max}$:

[image: Plot of v/[S] vs v]

From the equation of the graph: $\text{|The slope|} = 0.0102$ and $y\text{-Intercept} = 0.054$

Thus, $K_M = \pu{0.0102 mol L-1}$ and $V_\mathrm{max} = \pu{0.054 mol L-1 s-1}$

Once I found OP's mistake of plotting, I was curious to see how this set of data would show the Lineweaver-Burk relationship. Thus, I make the table for $\frac{1}{[S]}$ and $\frac{1}{v}$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c} 
\hline
\dfrac{1}{[S]}, \ \pu{L mol-1} & \dfrac{1}{v}, \ \pu{L s mol-1} \\ \hline
4.99  & 19.42 \times 10^{-2}\\
19.98 & 22.32 \times 10^{-2}\\ 
59.70  & 29.85 \times 10^{-2}\\ 
199.44  & 55.56 \times 10^{-2}\\ 
1004.17  & 208.33 \times 10^{-2}\\ 
\hline
\end{array}$$

As predicted by  Lineweaver-Burk, the plot of $\frac{1}{[S]}$ versus $\frac{1}{v}$ is a straight-line with a positive slope:

[image: Plot of 1/[S] vs 1/v]

From the equation $(2)$, which is the equation of the graph: $\text{The slope} = 0.1891 = \frac{K_M}{V_\mathrm{max}}$ and $y\text{-Intercept} = 18.379 = \frac{1}{V_\mathrm{max}}$

Thus, $V_\mathrm{max} = \frac{1}{18.379} = \pu{0.0544 mol L-1 s-1}$ and $K_M = 0.1891 \times V_\mathrm{max} = 0.1891 \times 0.0544 = \pu{0.0103 mol L-1}$

Both graph give the same values for $K_M$ and $V_\mathrm{max}$.

Comment: Very nice answer indeed: went the extra mile! Glad I was the first upvoter! It should get the green checkmark ASAP!

Comment: Thank you very much! Truly appreciate it!